# Choosing Senators

Tags: probability

Just working my way through the W.Feller introduction to probability theory and its applications volume 1. An example in the chapter on combinatorial analysis asks the question:

"Each of the 50 states has 2 senators. If we choose 50 senators at random, what is the probability a given state is represented?"

I understand the answer given which uses the complement of the event but was curious whether the method where you force the desired outcome to occur, then work out how many ways the remaining cells can be chosen, would work here too?

AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that alternative method would work fine.  But you need to keep an inclusion/exclusion effect in mind.

Suppose that the senators in the state of interest are $A$ and $B$. There are $\pmatrix{100\\50}$ ways of choosing the fifty senators.  Of these, $\pmatrix{99\\49}$  will include $A$ and $\pmatrix{99\\49}$ will include $B$.  However, $\pmatrix{98\\48}$ will include both!  The probability is therefore:

$$
\frac{2\pmatrix{99\\49}-\pmatrix{98\\48}}{\pmatrix{100\\50}}.$$

---

The easiest way I can think of to use a method based on complements is this:
There are $\pmatrix{100\\50}$ ways of choosing the 50 senators, and $\pmatrix{98\\ 50}$ ways to choose the 50 without including either $A$ or $B$.  The probability of excluding both $A$ and $B$ is therefore:
$$
1-\frac{\pmatrix{98\\50}}{\pmatrix{100\\50}}.$$

It's easy to see numerically that these methods agree, but you should try an analytic (algebraic) proof to verify that these methods agree for the more general case of choosing $k$ senators from a population of $n$ when excluding 2 (or more, although then the inclusion/exclusion calculations are trickier).

Comment: Excellent answer! Exactly what I was wanting to know. Your second method is the same as Feller's. Thanks